# UICollectionViewDataSource methods are not getting called when data-source is a separate class

Tags: uicollectionview, single-responsibility-principle

I created a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell` and a separate data-source class `DataSource` for this collection-view.

`DataSource` conforms to the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol and I have also assigned the `dataSource` of an instance of `DataSource` in my collection-view container class.

But none of the data-source methods in `DataSource` are getting called.

*It was working fine before I created a separate class for `UICollectionView` data-source.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved!**

*It was a stupid mistake.* I hadn't created the instance variable to retain the instance of `DataSource` in my collection-view container class, so it was getting released as soon as the method where it was getting `alloc-init`ed finished.